# blank div on ie but not blank

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

for example have a div,html code below

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

but when i set the innerHTML property of the `div(id=testDiv)` on ie ,see the code below:

```
document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML= '';
```

and the div will have a height and width,not a blank div any more
so that is why??
if i want the div is a blank div when set the innerHTML=''(if do not set the display:none)，how should i do?
now  show the test code(different results runing  on  ***ie7*** and chrome)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        #bl{background:red;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(a){
    var t=document.getElementById("bl");
    t.innerHTML=a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button"  onclick="f('')">test</button>
    <div id="bl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried double quotes instead of single? And, what do you mean with not blank?

Comment: can you post your html code ?

Comment: please share your code, i am not able to replicate with <div onClick="javascript:this.innerHTML=''" style="border:1px solid #000"></div> in IE8 (the styling is so i can see the box and click on it)

Comment: What version of IE?  I'm trying your example in IE9 and see no changes to the div.

Comment: i see no difference ...using IE8 and firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known IE behaviour.
In addition to setting `innerHTML` to empty string you can also set `font-size` to 0.

Comment: but if i set innerHTML ='myvalue',and the text will not been seen any move

Comment: set `font-size` back to original value or `inherit`

Comment: that is the reason why i don't want use the display:none,if there is a method like trigger the haslayout attribute,and let it shows on ie with standard

Answer (score 2):

In your function, check if the text is `''`, and if so, remove the child node from the div. instead of setting its value.

```
if (a=='') t.removeChild(t.childNodes[0]);
else t.innerHTML=a;
```

Checked in IE8 and in IE8's compatibility mode (so it should work in IE7 too).

For more stability, you can remove all child nodes from `t`, like so...

```
if (a=='') {while (t.hasChildNodes() t.removeChild(t.childNodes[0]);}
else t.innerHTML=a;
```